# Is this sentence correct "I'll do whatever depend on me"?

Tags: grammar

don't I need to use the ending "s" after word depend? Don't I? I don't have this question almost in any cases but now I am confused because  I've already used Future Simple before the word "whatever". I would be really glad to hear the answers

Comment: It isn’t clear in the question what you’re intended meaning is.  You could also make it grammatical like this: “*I’ll do whatever [you need]. [ You can] Depend on me.* “

Answer (score 2):

*Depends* is correct because *whatever* is singular. This has nothing to do the use of future simple in the preceding part of the sentence: it is just a matter of subject-verb agreement in the noun clause.

However, the sentence makes very little sense even with the correct conjugation.

Comment: “I will do whatever I can; you can always depend on me.”

Comment: That's a fair guess at what he meant, but the original sentence still does not follow. In any case, the meaning of the sentence is independent of the question "should I use *depend* or *depends*?"

Comment: It is answered already by me--use " depends " as "whatever" is singular, dear.

Comment: I want to vote this answer but I don't have enough reputation for now. Please, explain to me why this sentence doesn't have sense.

Comment: "I'll do _" suggests the blank is an action. However, "_ depends on me" suggests the blank is a person or similar entity. Abhilaaj and Jim suggest valid alternatives. You can always "accept" an answer without voting -- click the grey checkmark under the score.